# Limit scp (with sshd on centos) speed / rate

Tags: linux, centos, bandwidth, scp, ssh

I'd like to let users download / upload files via scp to my centos 6.0 system, it's connected to lan via Gigabit ethernet, but I don't want transfers to flow at that speed.
I want to limit the speed to 10Mb/s.

I have managed to find the right configuration for vsftpd to limit the rate, but failing to find the same for sshd.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Edit : Just to make it clearer, I am trying to limit the max speed on the server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to implement QOS which won't differentiate between ssh and scp (since scp uses ssh protocol on the same port).

Comment: Also see <http://serverfault.com/questions/146010/cisco-ios-qos-prioritize-ssh-but-not-scp> on how it is possible (to some extent) to differentiate between ssh and scp.

Comment: Today I learned something, cool!

Comment: Hmmm. Too bad there is no simple way like there is for vsftpd, I think i'll just use iptables or tc qdisc (netm)